# Issuing an asnyc I/O on a page

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I was wondering what the correct way of issuing an asynchronous read operation on a page that has been swapped out is. And once this is done is there a way to execute a callback that happens so that I can execute some logic with that page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`madvise(start_address, length, MADV_WILLNEED)` will do that.

A callback does not really exist, though you can poll a snapshot of the status with the `mincore` syscall, if you want.

Note that the opposite hint `MADV_DONTNEED` does **not** do what you think, nor does `msync`. The documentation is lying.
There is no non-broken-by-design way to start asynchronous *writeback* under Linux (although the documentation says so). You can choose between no-op, throwing pages away, synchronous writeback, or asynchronous writeback with purging the cache.

Comment: That's for userspace programs, I need one for the kernel to actually force an async I/O for a userspace page from the kernel

Comment: Then you probably want `force_page_cache_readahead` (in mm/readahead.c). It's what `madvise` uses too. See: [madvise_willneed](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ze679yAWiJU/mm/madvise.c&q=madvise%20package:linux-2.6&type=cs&l=144)

Comment: That's the method I was looking at but is there a way to know when the page(s) are all read into memory?

Comment: None that I'm aware of (other than checking manually), but there might of course be.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I guess the manual checks I'm using are gonna have to stay :) (for now)

Comment: What about `sync_file_range(..., SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE)` for initiating asynchronous writeout ([as recommended by Linus](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/5/19/410))?

Comment: Apart from the wording "extremely dangerous" in the manpage and the comments in the sources saying "may block for significant periods" (even though the manpage says "asynchronous"), and apart from being totally non-portable, yes. It will likely do the job, more often than not. However, it's the same thing as with `msync`. You can't rely on it, and it does not work as advertized. It would be nice if a function just did what the manpage promises, instead of something different because someone thought something different is just as good... :(